# ispmanager mysql settings empty. Edit button is disabled ((

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Ispmanager 5, CentOs 7

I just uninstall default Mysql with commands:

`service mariadb stop`

`yum remove mariadb mariadb-server`

Than upgraded it with mariadb 10.3:

`cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo <<EOF`

`# MariaDB.repo`

`# MariaDB 10.3 CentOS repository list`

`# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/`

`[mariadb]`

`name = MariaDB`

`baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.3/centos7-amd64`

`gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB`

`gpgcheck=1`

`EOF`

`yum -y install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client`

`mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld`

`chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld`

`systemctl enable mariadb`

`service mariadb start`

After this - all things working fine except this:

[image]

The server settings - is empty. Edit button is disabled.

PS: /etc/my.cnf is on its place, `mysql --help` shows than it uses /etc/my.cnf  and ~/my.cnf

Comment: Sergey, it looks like a bug

Comment: @HoRn, Thanks for your reply. Nope )) It's not a bug.  It's my fail. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the parameter to new path

> path mysqld usr/sbin/mysqld

in **/usr/local/mgr5/etc/ispmgr.conf.d/mysql.conf**

Because new version of mariadb uses another path of the mysqld.
After this all things works like a charm )))